# Is there any way to change the page template and component template via automation using core services?

Tags: core-service, templating, componentpresentation

We have a requirement to change the page templates and component templates to a newer version available for all our pages and components via automation. Are there any extensions available or any plugins we can use to achieve the same using the core services. Any suggestion or the sample code snippet would be of great help. Thanks!

Comment: In general, you can change any property of any item using the (public) Core Service API. It's not clear to me what kind of "extension or plugin" you are looking for?

Comment: @RickPannekoek Can you help us with any code snippet if available. Thanks!

Comment: There are quite a few examples you can find through Google, and also in docs.rws.com, I’d recommend starting there